# With a given permutation $π$, how many functions $f: N_{10} → N_{10}$ are $f(π(i)) = πf(i)$, where all $i ∈ N_{10}$?

Tags: group-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, permutations

For how many functions $f: N_{10} → N_{10}$ are $f(π(i)) = πf(i)$, where all $i ∈ N_{10}$

The permutation $π ∈ S_{10}$ is given by:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
i& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
π(i) & 9 & 7 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Hi everyone, this is a question from a previous test in my current class, so I already know the answer (which I'm gonna write). However, I do not understand the answer, can someone possibly simplify the answer or maybe put it in a relatable context or give some other solution that might make me understand. Thanks!

Solution: In cycle notation we have $π(i) = (1, 9, 6)(2, 7)(3, 10)(4)(5, 8)$. A function $f$ satiesfies the condition ($f(π(i)) = πf(i)$) if $f(i)$ belongs to a $m$-cycle, with $m | k$, if $i$ is from a $k$-cycle (because $f(i)=f(π^k(i))=π^k(f(i))$).
The number of such $f$ is therefore $4*7*7*1*7=1372$ (possible choices for $f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5)$).

Ok, so that is it. The first hurdle I would say is; how do I realise that ($f(π(i)) = πf(i)$) if $f(i)$ belongs to a $m$-cycle, with $m | k$, if $i$ is from a $k$-cycle, and how do I get from there to $4*7*7*1*7=1372$?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It is difficult to know what exactly what it is that you do not understand. Your cycle $(310)$ looks confusing because it is actually the cycle $(3,10)$ of length $2$. An element in a cycle of length $3$ must map under $f$  to one in a cycle of length $3$ or $1$, so $f(1)$ must be 1, 9, 6, or 4, which explains the four possibilities for $f(1)$.